# Why I do get text/plain and text/x-java for two different js files?

Tags: linux, shell, files, mime-types

I use `/usr/bin/file -i file_path` to get information about my files.

I have a simple website project, in which I have a couple of js files.

When I use `/usr/bin/file -i file_name.js` for some of them, I get this result:

> file_name.js: text/plain; charset=utf-8

But for some other files, I get this result:

> file_name.js: text/x-java; charset=utf-8

Since I'm using a quality control utility that is dependent upon file types, this inconsistency results in errors.

Why is it so? What stuff should I check or troubleshoot? And how?

Comment: Which one do you consider correct? How do the files differ? Can you provide an example of one that produces `text/x-java`? `text/x-java` should denote Java source, not Javascript source.

Comment: I think there's a reason why `file`'s data sources are named "magic". It's finding something in the contents of the js file that makes it think it's java source.

Answer (score 3):

On my system a break down of what `file` guessed on the files whose name ends in `.js` (I don't know how many of them are actually meant to be javascript files):

```
$ locate -e0 '*.js' | xargs -r0 file -b --mime-type | sort | uniq -c
     60 application/json
     18 application/octet-stream
      1 application/x-terminfo
      1 inode/directory
     62 inode/symlink
    259 inode/x-empty
      1 regular file, no read permission
      2 text/csv
    220 text/html
  13342 text/plain
     30 text/x-Algol68
      6 text/x-asm
    126 text/x-c
     32 text/x-c++
     41 text/x-java
     15 text/x-perl
     82 text/x-tex
```

`file` just guesses at file types by reading their contents using heuristics. For text files with no always clear differentiator between them like javascript, C, C++, Java source files, the guesses tend to be wild.

AFAICT, the only files that `file` reports as `application/javascript` are the ones that have a `#!` she-bang referring to the nodejs interpreter. The ones reported as `text/x-java` are the ones that have a line that starts with `import` and ends in `;`.

Note that writing code that is valid in several languages is an art, called *polyglot coding*. There's a whole [category of Q&As about it on codegolf.stackexchange.com](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/polyglot), which demonstrates it's not always possible in the general case to identify with certainty a programming language from the contents of a file. All you can do is say: it looks like it could be javascript or C++, etc.